# Flask Application on docker ,Windows 10 pro - OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: docker, flask

I am using Docker(Linux Container) on Windows 10 Pro. I created a docker build for the flask application. After i run the application i get the PermissionError:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/app.py'

After referring some posts i have created the user and added the permissions in the dockerfile,still this doesn't work

**1.docker  version**

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2

 API version:       1.39

 Go version:        go1.10.8

 Git commit:        6247962

 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019

 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64

 Experimental:      false


Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2

  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)

  Go version:       go1.10.6

  Git commit:       6247962

  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019

  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64

  Experimental:     false
```

**2.Docker file**

```
FROM python:3.7.3

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin

COPY . /app 

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r "requirements.txt"

RUN chown -R admin:admin /app

RUN chmod 776 /app

USER admin

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["app.py"]
```

**3.Requirements file**

```
flask
tensorflow-gpu
flask_cors
uuid
librosa
numba
pysoundfile
numpy
cffi
requests
wave
h5py
pydub
werkzeug
```

**4.Error Log**

```
 File "app.py", line 552, in <module>
    app.run(debug = True, host = '0.0.0.0')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1007, in run_simple
run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/app.py'
```

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: i am using below commands from  command prompt -   Build :  "docker build -t wl:latest . "                                                                                                  Run  :   "docker  run -p 5000:5000 wl:latest"

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is `RUN chmod 776 /app`, you just change the permission of the folder, not the permission of `/app/app.py`.

You should use `RUN chmod -R 776 /app` to replace the old one, then `app.py` will have execution permission.

In fact in your case, `python app.py` already run successfuly, this is because when use `python` to call script, it's ok even if the py file has no execution permission. But things a little different for `flask application`, you can see from your log:

> reloader.restart_with_reloader()
>   exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)

The flask will call the top script again as subprocess, here, it will call `/app/app.py`. This time, it will just execute it as `/app/app.py`, not `python /app/app.py`, this means the file `app.py` had to have the execution permission.

Additional reminder, you need to add `#!` at the start of your `app.py`, something like next if you have other issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: error related to app.py is resolved, but i ran into another issue after the docker run -   
      OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/app\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown.